# How javascript function with 'return as function' works

Tags: javascript, function, return-type

I am trying to understand how javascript function returns function handle and why following code prints '2' instead of '1'

```js
var num = 01;
function processAndIncrement() {
  var process = function() { 
    console.log(num); 
  }
  num++;
  return process;
}
var proCall =  processAndIncrement();
proCall();
```

Comment: Yes, it returns a function handle. Which, when called, will output the current value of `num`. What in particular do you not understand about that, why did you expect it to log `1` (and never increment)?

Comment: The call to `processAndIncrement` increments `num` (which is a global variable)  and return another function that logs `num` (which is now `2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `num` variable is independent of the functions in your code. Both functions refer to the same variable, so they both mutate the same data and observe the changes.

So the `num++` operation increments `num` before `proCall` is ever invoked. When `proCall` is finally invoked, it sees the incremented state of `num`, because it has already been incremented.

---

Here's a step-by-step description of the order of operations (ignoring hoisting). Follow the sequence of numbers.

```
// 1. create the variable
var num = 01;

// 2. create the processAndIncrement function
function processAndIncrement() {

  // 4. Assign a function that logs `num` to the `process` variable
  var process = function() { 

    // 8. log the current value of `num` (which was incremented at step 5)
    console.log(num); 
  }

  // 5. increment `num`
  num++;

  // 6. return the `process` function
  return process;
}

// 3. Invoke processAndIncrement, and assign its return value to `proCall`
var proCall =  processAndIncrement();

// 7. invoke `proCall` (which is the same as the `process` function)
proCall();
```

If you wanted the increment to happen when `proCall` is invoked, then `num++` should be moved to be inside the `process` function.

Answer (score 1):

The Code prints `2` because you increment `num` which's value is already `1` (01 == 1).